# Download pdfs and not show in the browser

Tags: php, html

I have links in my web page that point to PDFs, that are in my server. 
I don't want want pdfs to be viewed in the browser bur directly downlodable when a user click on the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the right header info. PHP file should look something like this.

```
<? 
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  readfile('huge_document.pdf');
?>
```

as depicted here

http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Regards